# What is the location of lock screen images on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, images, desktop-customization, windows-spotlight

Where, or what format, are the images used by Windows 10 when logged out or in lock-screen?

I searched the entire drive for *.jpg, *.bmp, *.png, and *.tif but the one I was looking for did not appear.

At first glance, [Path to current desktop backgrounds in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/966650/path-to-current-desktop-backgrounds-in-windows-10), although not exactly a duplicate, appeared to have the path I wanted.  But when I went there, the pre-login image was there, but the lock-screen image was not.  (And contrary to the claim in that answer, the files there **did** have extensions.)

UPDATE: I just did a lockscreen, and got an image that IS in that directory, but earlier today, it was consistently an image of an interesting footbridge that is **not** in that directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path to current desktop backgrounds in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/966650/path-to-current-desktop-backgrounds-in-windows-10)

Comment: Sorry, the lock-screen image was _not_ in that ...\web directory.  It did look like a duplicate, and I almost agreed, but then thought I should look first.  It's unfortunate (just my opinion) that most of the time, the "suggestions" contain no real duplicate, yet as soon as I submit the question, several actual duplicates appear in the right sidebar.

Comment: @DavidPostill, 'Lock screen image' != 'desktop background papger'

Comment: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets

Comment: @aderchox that shows other Microsoft images, but not user images.

Comment: @DavidPostill a background image is totally different than a lockscreen image.  The lockscreen is the screen you see before you logon.  The background screen is the image you see in your background after you logon.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you are not finding the images in the typical locations, you likely have `Windows Spotlight` turned on. Spotlight offers random images on the lock screen, as well as other features.

> These Windows Spotlight images aren’t stored in the same location as
>   regular Windows wallpaper, however, so here’s how you can find them.

The images are **hidden** deep, so you will need to change settings before you can view them. To do this, open File Explorer and go to the `View` tab. On the far right is an `Options` button, click it.

In the window that opens, select the `View` tab. Under `Advanced Settings`, select `Show hidden files, folders and drives`, then click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and then <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the open window.

Now it is time to navigate to the following directory (which was hidden before).

**`This PC > C: > Users > [Your User Name] > AppData > Local > Packages > Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy > LocalState > Assets`**

In this directory you will see a bunch of files without extensions. These are the incognito image files. These are `jpeg` images of various resolutions to meet the needs of multiple devices screen sizes. You can copy the files to another location and rename them to have the `jpeg` extension, then you can open them with your default image viewer.

[source](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/find-windows-spotlight-lock-screen-images-windows-10/)

Comment: Have to rename them all just to look for one.  Bummer.  Guess I can do that trivially in a Unix shell, but that means sending them all over the wire.  Well, I'll try it next time I'm on the Windows box.

Comment: Yeah, it's inconvenient. MS was trying to hide them and not make it easy to get. I'm sure you can view them one by one by using the `Open with...` function, until you find the one you want.

Comment: I am not sure saying MS was trying to hide then is fair, the directory, matches the naming convention of a UWP.  Pretty sure it's more like they didn't expect anyone to care where the images were

Comment: True. Purely speculation on my part. I don't know MS's motive. My point was; they didn't put them in a place where they are easily accessible within the user profile.

Comment: A bit late but fwiw I'm using a batch renamer to add the .jpg extension. There are plenty out there (I use one called Advanced Renamer, it's pretty decent).

Comment: If you have copied the files (that are JPEG files but have no extension) to a temporary directory, where you don’t have any other files, you can rename them all from the Command Prompt with `ren *. *.jpg`

Comment: note perhaps microsoft changed something but this answer doesn't work for me anymore as of fall 2018. The Assets folder exists, and there *are* dozens of long random-char names without extensions, and they *are* pictures when renamed to jpg, but they are all under 150 kb, and the largest ones are a bunch of candy-crush game art, not the gorgeous lock screen wallpapers.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me considering I wrote this answer 2 years ago. There have been so many major changes to Windows since then. :-)

Comment: To rename the files copy to a directory. Then open cmd, navigate to that directory and type "ren star dot star star dot jpg" which will bulk rename them all to jpg.

Comment: Im using windows 1903 and this still works for me.

Comment: its still working on Windows 10 in Nov 2019

Comment: These are NOT lockscreen images.  It also doesn't contain any user created lockscreen images.

Comment: A quick way of getting to the folder is by opening File Explorer and typing into the address bar at the top `%appdata%\..\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`.  You don't need to unhide hidden folders to do so either

Answer (score 35):

All above did not worked for me at all.
Lock screen was still that `annoying-cave-entrance`.

No matter if I overwrite that `Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets` folder.

No matter if I replace\edit anything in `Windows\Web\Screen` folder.

Even `gpedit.msc` did not help.

Lock screen/logon screen was still that frakin `annoying-cave-entrance`screen.

If it shows that screen, then **it has to be somewhere** on the disk.

I found it eventually in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData`.

That `SystemData` folder have to be changed with security edits (you need to take ownership of that folder and its content through properties window, Security tab)

After that you will have to edit picture files within subfolders (depending on how many users are set on the computer).

There will be several folders which could look like:

```
- S-1-5-18\ReadOnly\LockScreen_X (and other LockScreen_Y, LockScreen_Z)

- S-1-5-21-...\ReadOnly\LockScreen_O

- S-1-5-21-...\ReadOnly\LockScreen_O
```

Hope it will help to some :)

Comment: I didn't have access to that folder nor the ability to change permissions through windows explorer, but I was able to do whatever I want (including overwriting files and successfully changing my background image!) via git bash instead. Thanks!

Comment: You have to "take ownership" of the folder in Windows and you can edit files then. You can do so with command line (takeown && icacls) or you can find some "registry hacks" online

Comment: Exactly what I needed - THANK YOU!!

Comment: I had to take ownership of the SystemData folder.   
Running from an Administrator command prompt I issued the following command:
takeown /F C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\ /r /d Y

Comment: Thank you!  This is the right answer.  Also thanks to @JoeB, that worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Ariel and @JoeB. This way I found the one pretty image missing from my collection, when it reappeared as a lock screen image. Would you recommend undoing the taking of ownership? Can I unwittingly do some damage if I don't :-)

Comment: Instead of taking ownership of the folder and changing the access rights, you can also use a tool like PsExec to spawn a shell running in the SYSTEM account, and then do whatever you want. Beware though, SYSTEM can basically do anything, so if you type the wrong command, you can destroy your system...

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer(s) given, I'd like to provide you with a script that instantly copies and renames the file to *.jpg. If you change the view to medium icons or to large icons, then you can instantly see the pictures when you run the script (let's name it `LikeWhatYouSee.cmd`):

```shell
:: Batch script, which copies "Like what you see" 
:: pictures to %userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\ and opens it in explorer
cd /D %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
mkdir "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\" 1>nul 2>&1
copy * "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\*.jpg"
explorer "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\"
```

The pictures are saved to the subdirectory **`Saved Pictures`** in your user profile's **`Pictures`** folder. You can run the script multiple times without harm, the pictures have unique filenames. Over time, you will get a lot of nice pictures in that folder. The pictures will not be removed from there, unless you delete them manually.

**Note:** After you ran the script above, you can change the lock screen image to any of the liked pictures you saved easily. To do this:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open Windows settings
2. Click "Personalization"
3. In the side bar, select "Lock screen"
4. In the lock screen settings, select "Picture" (always the same image) or "Slideshow" (alternating images) as background
5. If you selected "Picture", you can click "Browse" to find and select your picture. If you selected "Slideshow", you can click on "+" to add a folder. For the folder, browse to Pictures --> Saved Pictures, where you can find the pictures saved by the script

---

**Note:** You might have noticed that the script above copies all images. Sometimes there are also icons included in the Windows content delivery folder, which you don't want to copy. One simple way is to limit the size and copy only larger files.

With this modified script you can do that (for a more detailed description how it works, look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/877976/windows-command-line-to-move-files-over-a-certain-size)):

```shell
:: Batch script, which copies larger "Like what you see" 
:: pictures to %userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\ and opens it in explorer
cd /D %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
mkdir "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\" 1>nul 2>&1
for /r ".\" %%F in (*) do @if %%~zF geq 35000 copy "%%F" "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\*.jpg"
explorer "%userprofile%\Pictures\Saved Pictures\"
```

Comment: Using the %userprofile% is the best way to get the location, works regardless of what the user's username is

Answer (score 3):

For my company win10 locked locked screen background, i did not have access to Windows\Web\Screen folder because I'm not admin.

But

In the photo win10 app, i coul right click and choose MY picture and then select : choose as (français: établir en tant que...) locked screen background.

Hope this helps any of you change annoying locked admin parameters!!

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out already, the images are located at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`.

This location does not only contain the desktop wallpapers, but also icons, wallpapers in portrait format and other files. All files do not have file extensions, so you cannot view them by double clicking or having a preview.

The following PowerShell script will copy all desktop wallpapers (image width >= 1920) to your desktop, while renaming the files and adding the `.jpg` extension:

```
$folder = New-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Name "Windows_Wallpapers_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss'))" -ItemType Directory
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets"
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $image = New-Object -ComObject WIA.ImageFile
    try {
        $image.LoadFile(($file.FullName))
        if ($image.Width -ge 1920) {
            Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$($folder.FullName)\Image_$($counter.ToString('0000')).jpg"
            $counter++
        }
    } catch {}
}
```