# windows 10 spotlight images are not in the Assets folder, contrary to previous answers

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization, lock-screen

I'm using windows 10, and in the lock screen I see very nice scenery wallpaper. I'm trying to grab those jpg files so I can manually set them as my *desktop* wallpaper too. Doing this seems well documented, as in [this previous thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10). Also, a google search shows many sites also pointing to `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`. We're supposed to go to that directory, and copy and rename the largest files there to jpg, then we have the scenery pictures and can do whatever we want with them.

Now it's fall 2018, and it appears there's one issue: that directory still contains files, and they are pictures when renamed to jpg, but the issue is that the largest file is 150 kb, and they are just a bunch of gaming art, candy-crush saga, stuff like that. There's *no* wallpaper there. From [this cnet guide from 2016, which contain screenshots of that directory](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/where-to-find-the-windows-spotlight-photos/), it appears that previously, some of the files in that directory can go up to 500 kb and even 1 mb. However, again, in my Assets directory the largest is only 150 kb, and are a bunch of random gaming art pictures.

Just to make sure that the lock screen displays the wallpaper, I clicked lock, and the wallpaper is displayed. Is windows deleting the pictures too fast for me to notice, or have they changed the location of the large scenery lockscreen wallpapers?

EDIT: I'm running windows 10 pro, version 1803, build 17134.1 on a dell latitude. I downloaded and installed windows from the official iso just yesterday, oct 2018.

EDIT: changed title from "location of windows 10 spotlight images changed recently, previous answers invalid"

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you running? I believe this information is significant to identifying the problem.

Comment: Also, is this a fresh install of whichever build you're on or did you upgrade from a previous build? Is Spotlight working?

Comment: @Run5k OP states that answer's location is no longer valid. We need more information from them before we can note this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Run5k this is not a duplicate; I already have a link to that the thread at the very beginning of my question. My question is saying the answer in that link doesn't work because the pictures aren't in the directory that answer is saying.

Comment: Ok, then no, that is still the very much correct location. Spotlight may not be working, or it just may not have downloaded any images yet. It doesn't pre-load a bunch of images. It downloads them based on criteria we are not aware of at intervals. If you have a fresh install, it will not have previous Spotlight images.

Comment: Also, we can be pretty sure it's not changing in build 1809 either. I'm running the Insider Preview Fast Ring with Skip Ahead (so, as far ahead in builds as you can get publicly right now) in a VM, and there are Spotlight files dropped yesterday morning in that same directory.

Comment: @music2myear, I always appreciate your feedback and while I understand what you're saying, the underlying goal of this question is still the same.  It seems as though this should have been either a comment on the original question, or perhaps even a bounty asking for the "new" solution.

Comment: Well, now that OP has answered and updated his question, it is more of a duplicate, but possibly not of that one. Spotlight may be broken on their computer.

Comment: @Run5k I made a comment on the original question before posting this question. As the original question is more than a year old, that comment hasn't gotten any responses, and may not for a while. Also, while the goal is the same as in the previous question, I think the fact that there appears to be a major flaw with the procedure in that answer (e.g. the files aren't where the answer say they will be) make it at least reasonable for this to be a new question, especially since I already acknowledged the existence of the old thread in the very beginning of my post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and it was embarrassingly simple. The wifi on that machine was manually turned off for another unrelated reason so spotlight wasn't actually working, as a previous comment pointed out. When the internet was re-enabled, several wallpaper images >500 kb immediately appeared in the assets folder.

(one part is slightly strange though; when wifi was not enabled, the lock screen still did have one background image, and *that* image wasn't in the assets folder).