# How to change SystemData folder properties?

Tags: windows, lock-screen, user-folders, properties

I foun the pathway in [What is the location of lock screen images on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10) [What is the location of lock screen images on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126403/what-is-the-location-of-lock-screen-images-on-windows-10), which retrieved to [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData] folder, to find the windows' screen lock images; I tryed  by using MS-DOS "attrib command" [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows>attrib *.* -r -a -s -h -o -i -x -p -u /s /d /l], with "dennied access" at every file and folder. I also check the folder's properties in the "security tab", with no result.

Comment: If you wish to post your own question and answer it you should not simply post the answer in your question. You should post a complete and self contained question and then you can post the answer below that. It might help to take the [tour] and read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Alternatively if you wish to post an additional answer to the other question it requires only 10 reputation, something that is easily achievable by posting a good answer of your own elsewhere and getting a single upvote.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guide, I´ll do as you said.

Comment: You can and should add pictures to the lock screen without changing folder permissions

Answer (score 0):

I saw the video [Windows 10 And 8.1 Change System Files And Folder User Permissions (ACL)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LnnvbpO9NI).  I couldn't follow the same pathway in the video, roughly following the steps and after accepting the warnings, I could get in the folder [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-21-710694829-1101361531-374231197-1001\ReadOnly\LockScreen_O], and found the start up´s lock screen images.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thnak you very much for this counselor.